# How to abort a long query when the application is stopped

Tags: go

My application has a database query that can take a very long time to complete. It runs in a separate goroutine.

```
func main() {
    ///...
    go func() {
        ctx, cancelFunc := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 3*time.Minute)
        defer cancelFunc()

        rows, err := db.QueryContext(ctx, "very long query")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Failed to execute query:", err)
            return
        }
        ///...
    }()

    ///...

}
```

How can I interrupt it when the application stops?
I tried to solve it like this but read that it's bad practice to cause a context stop in another goroutine

```
func main() {
    ///...
    stop := make(chan struct{})
    go func(chan struct{}) {
        ctx, cancelFunc := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 3*time.Minute)
        defer cancelFunc()

        go func() {
            <-stop
            fmt.Println("Received interrupt signal, canceling request...")
            cancelFunc()
        }()
        rows, err := db.QueryContext(ctx, "very long query")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Failed to execute query:", err)
            return
        }
        ///...
    }(stop)

    ///...

    stop <- struct{}{}
}
```

Comment: I can propose you to implement [Closer](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Closer). I think it is ok if you will send any stop message to all goroutines that related to same struct. I.e. you can have some `Storage` struct and some methods of this struct can run goroutines with SQL queries. If `Storage` also implements `Closer` it is good practise to stop all of them in `Close` method of `Storage`. I would like also recommend you to read how to implement graceful shutdown for go applications.

Comment: _"I tried to solve it like this but read that it's bad practice to cause a context stop in another goroutine"_ Where did you read this?

Comment: It's perfectly fine to cancel the context from another go routine as context are safe for concurrent use. Where did you read it? Typically "a main" context is given to all such long running tasks, and when the program stops it cancels the main context and all tasks should be cancelled. In your case you're using an internal context just for the query, so you cannot pass in the "main" program context also. In this case I think it's OK to cancel the internal context from a separate go routine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to pass the global context (created in the main) to your function with a request to the database, and when you cancel this global context, your request will also be canceled